# How to create virtual directory in G-WAN webserver

Tags: g-wan, virtual-hosts

I installed G-WAN webserver , and i create virtual host , in G-WAN we must create folder for virtual host's , now i want to create virtual directory

my installed path is :

```
/home/gwan/
```

and myfiles are in

```
/home/user/
```

so how can i create virtual directory for virtual host ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve on your question. Did you mean you want the files on /home/user/ accessible on your website?

Comment: Not sure that symlinks are working ... at least my latests tests failed ...

Answer (score 0):

When we created G-WAN, we worked hard to remove any possible configuration issue by *not* using files where you have to tell the server what to do.

The simplest way to use your files located under `/home/user/` is to either copy the G-WAN execuatble there or to copy your `www files` under the `/home/gwan` folder.

If you really want to use G-WAN, you should consider to read its documentation or at least its FAQs which both explain [how to setup hosts](http://gwan.ch/faq#listener).